# Jquery simple realtime calculator

Tags: jquery, forms

I have very simple form where clients adds:

1. Number of charaters in a doc >>> then normalised pages (NP) are counted (Chars / 1800)
2. Check whether he wants to pay for quickier solution
3. Check whether he wants to correct grammar

Prices should be counted following way:

- less than 50 NP = 599; each +10 NP = 99
- quickier solution = +399
- correction of grammar = 39 per NS (if quickier solution 79 per NS)

It should be calculated realtime. I have a form:

```
<form action="" id="kalkulackaceny" onsubmit="return false;">

    <label>Number of Chars<input type="text" name="kyber-znaky"id="kyber-znaky"/><span id="totalNS"></span></label> 
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="kyber-specha" id="kyber-specha" val="yes"/> Spěchá to?</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"  name="kyber-korektura" id="kyber-korektura" val="yes"//> Korektura?</label>

</form>
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
```

And not updating jquery:

```
var cenaStd = 599;
var cenaDeset = 99;
var cenaSpechato = 399;
var cenaKorektura = 39;
var cenaKorekturaSpechato = 79;

$(document).ready(function(){

    //update znaky
    $('#kyber-znaky').keyup(function(){
        var ns = $('#kyber-znaky').val();
        ns = Math.round(ns/1800);

        if (ns < 50){
            finalPrice = cenaStd;
        }
        else {
            finalPrice = cenaStd;
            x = ns - 49;
            while (x > 0){
                finalPrice += cenaDeset;
                x -= 10;
            }
        }

        $('#totalNS').text(" (celkem " +ns+ " NS)");
        //$('#totalPrice').text("Celková cena za zakázku " +finalPrice);

    });

    $('#kyber-specha').change(function() {        
        if($('#kyber-specha:checked').val() == 'yes'){
            finalPrice += cenaSpechato;
        }               
    });
    $('#kyber-korektura').change(function() {
    if($('#kyber-specha:checked').val() == 'yes'){    
        if($('#kyber-specha:checked').val() == 'yes'){
            finalPrice += ns*cenaKorekturaSpechato;
        }
        else {
            finalPrice += ns*cenaKorektura;
        }
    }
    });

    $('#kalkulackaceny').on('change',function(){
        $('#totalPrice').text("Celková cena za zakázku " +finalPrice);
    });

});
```

I've add it to js fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kybernaut/7ubr4Luh/1/).

Could anybody help me to fix it? I'm a beginer with jquery. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have moved all caluclations to separate function: `calcPrice`.
I have also changed `Math.round(ns / 1800)` to `Math.ceil(ns / 1800)`. If you really want to exclude half filled pages from calculation then change it back.

```js
var cenaStd = 599;
var cenaDeset = 99;
var cenaSpechato = 399;
var cenaKorektura = 39;
var cenaKorekturaSpechato = 79;

var calcPrice = function(sett) {
  var pages = sett.pages >= 0 ? sett.pages : 0,
    correct = sett.correct,
    fast = sett.fast,
    totalPrice,
    tensOver50 = Math.ceil(Math.max(0, pages - 49) / 10);

  totalPrice = cenaStd + tensOver50 * cenaDeset;
  if (fast) {
    totalPrice += cenaSpechato;
  }
  if (correct) {
    totalPrice += pages * (fast ? cenaKorekturaSpechato : cenaKorektura)
  }
  return totalPrice;
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  var paramsChanged = function() {
    var ns = parseInt($('#kyber-znaky').val());
    ns = Math.ceil(ns / 1800);

    var settings = {
      fast: $('#kyber-specha:checked').length === 1,
      correct: $('#kyber-korektura:checked').length === 1,
      pages: ns
    };
    var finalPrice = calcPrice(settings);

    //update display:
    $('#totalNS').text(" (celkem " + ns + " NS)");
    $('#totalPrice').text("Celková cena za zakázku " + finalPrice);
  }

  //update znaky
  $('#kyber-znaky').keyup(paramsChanged);
  $('#kyber-specha, #kyber-korektura').change(paramsChanged);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="kalkulackaceny" onsubmit="return false;">

  <label>Number of Chars
    <input type="text" name="kyber-znaky" id="kyber-znaky" /><span id="totalNS"></span>
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="kyber-specha" id="kyber-specha" val="yes" />Spěchá to?</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="kyber-korektura" id="kyber-korektura" val="yes" //>Korektura?</label>

</form>
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
```